# Filter file system file selection dialog by ContentTypeId

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In the Eclipse plugins we're developing, we've defined a custom content type, using the `org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes` extension point. We're successfully using the content type to enable or disable UI components, based on, e.g., whether the user is editing a file of that type.

I'd like to take this ones step further and also use it to filter files in a file selection dialog, such that it only shows files that match the content type.

I have found that filtering a JFace Viewer this way [is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27971748/), so for files in the workspace, we could use an `ElementTreeSelectionDialog` and add a `ViewerFilter`.

Is there a way to do the same for a file selection dialog of the entire file system (instead of filtering by file extension)? Or is this impossible because it's restricted to the OS's filtering?

Comment: If you mean the SWT  `FileDialog` you can only use file extension filtering for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard SWT `FileDialog` can only be filtered by file extension and cannot be extended.

You could write your own file selection dialog using the normal Java `File` or `Path` APIs with a tree viewer and a viewer filter.

Because the files are outside of the workspace you can't use any of the `IResource`, `IFile`, `IFolder` APIs. However you can still use the `IContentTypeManager` interface which gives you access to your content types.

```java
IContentTypeManager manager = Platform.getContentTypeManager();
```

If the file extension is enough to distinguish the files you can just use:

```java
IContentType contentType = manager.findContentTypeFor("the file name");
```

If you need to use the content describers use:

```java
InputStream stream = ... new FileInputStream(....

IContentType contentType = manager.findContentTypeFor(stream, "the file name");

stream.close();
```

Comment: It's great that besides an answer about the (im)possibility of using the standard `FileDialog` for this purpose, you also gave a clear explanation as to how to create a dialog that does fit our needs. Thank you.